# Order of magnitude of tail of convergent series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2\ln{k}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I'm wanting to deduce that the convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2\ln{k}}}$ implies the following: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2\ln{k}}} = 0$$ This isn't a homework problem in and of itself, I need this result as a condition to invoke a theorem. So far, I am at a complete loss as to how to handle this. I couldn't even manage a useful inequality and quite frankly am not even sure it's true (clearly this is true for $\ln{n}$ and for $n^{\alpha}\ln(n), \alpha < 1$ which gives me hope).

Also, can this result be generalized? Is it always the case that a convergent series will have a tail of order of convergence over $n^\alpha$ for some $\alpha \geq 1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\sum_{n=N}^\infty n^{-a} \ln^b n \sim C n^{1-a}\ln^b N$ for some $C$, and $\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-n} = C e^{-N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{\log x}$ are decreasing functions on $[2,+\infty)$, for any $n\geq 2$
$$\sum_{k>n}\frac{1}{k^2\log k}\leq \frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k>n}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \frac{1}{\log n}\int_{n}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{n\log n}.$$
The generalization is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot deduce such a statement from convergence alone. Consider the example series $$\sum_{k=3}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\log n} - \frac{1}{\log (n-1)}\right).$$ It converges, because it telescopes to $\frac{1}{\log 2}$, but $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\log n} - \frac{1}{\log (n-1)}\right) = \frac{1}{\log n}$$ and therefore $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^\alpha \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\log n} - \frac{1}{\log (n-1)}\right) = \infty$$ for any $\alpha>0$.

In other words, a convergent series can converge arbitrarily slowly.